# Identify the selected dropdown option and add code to body

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery to change an attribute on `body` and it works when I change the dropdown option.
But what I need is for this event to fire when the option is already selected.

In this example the attribute is not added:
https://3brow.com/produto/camiseta-tigre/?attribute_pa_cor=verde&attribute_pa_estilo=polo&attribute_pa_tamanho=p

But once I change the select option the attribute is added.

```
E.g: <body produto="amarelo">
```

HTML

```
<select id="pa_cor" class="" name="attribute_pa_cor" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_cor" "="" data-show_option_none="yes" >
<option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
<option value="cinza" class="attached enabled">Cinza</option>
<option value="rosa" class="attached enabled">Rosa</option>
<option value="verde" class="attached enabled">Verde</option>
<option value="vermelho" class="attached enabled">Vermelho</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$('#pa_cor').change(function() {
    $('body').attr('produto', $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you detect that the option is already selected, you can fire the `change` event with the following code. Just make sure it is after your change declaration.

```
$('#pa_cor').change(function() {
    $('body').attr('produto', $(this).val());
});

//trigger the change event
$('#pa_cor').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Worked! Perfect! Thanks!